# Setting user accounts for Form Authentication SSRS

Tags: sql-server, ssrs, reporting

Is there a separate procedure to set up user/log in accounts for Form Authentication in Reporting Service? Can you refresh me on this? I am having difficulties with Log in to my report server. All I can find is Window Authentication Log in Configurations and was unable to find out about Form Authentication properly. It seems really difficult for me to do especially when I am not familiar with those. Hope someone could shed some light.

Comment: Hopefully this will point you in the right direction. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc281383(v=sql.110).aspx

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have gone thru this. The steps looks really straight forward but I can't run it successfully. There might be some thing missing in sql configuration or log-in user accounts settings that leads network-related issues like unable to connect to report server and access its user account database. How could I retrieve those account settings to amend them?